# Searching a framework for an Android backend with databases and REST service

Tags: android, rest, frameworks, backend

I want to implement a backend without doing it ll from scratch. Here is what it is supposed to to:

- Provide a Rest interface (Android clients can authenticate, query, download and upload)
- Handle a database (community contet; not completely synchronized with the clients)
- Has a file system for managing images and other content. The android client may request them either directly per REST or over HTTP
- Is based on Linux

I know that are well known big frameworks - but do you have any recommendations here for best practices that are easy to set up?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found q suitable way here, which is scalable. It makes use of the Google App Engine (App Engine Backend Application Project).

There is a tutorial on this [here](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/).